# SignalR JavaScript Client on Mobile Devices

Tags: android, ios, websocket, signalr, signalr-hub

As described in documentation SignalR the following transport mechanisms:

1. WebSocketsl;
2. Server Sent Events;
3. ForeverFrame;
4. LongPolling

and it will degrade automatically to the best option supported by the client.

My problems are:

SignalR javascript client (tested to work in all modern browsers on a PC) doesn't work on mobile devices until I specify explicitly to use LongPolling as a transport by writing this:

```
$.connection.hub.start({ transport: 'longPolling' });
```

Second problem is that, even if I specify the LongPolling option, it still doesn't work in native Android browsers.

Has anyone encountered or solved these problems?

Comment: Native Android Browser has given problems with Websockets and SSE. Long Polling is your best option and it usually works fine. Have you tried different devices? Have you tried installing Chrome on the same device? Could you add your client traces? simply override the function connection.log to display output on the webpage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I upgraded SignalR version to 2.0.1 and everything magically worked :) I recommend all to do so